# Julia DifferentialEquations.jl speed

Tags: julia, ode, differentialequations.jl

I am trying to test the speed of Julia ODE solvers. I used the Lorenz equation in the tutorial:

```
using DifferentialEquations
using Plots
function lorenz(t,u,du)
du[1] = 10.0*(u[2]-u[1])
du[2] = u[1]*(28.0-u[3]) - u[2]
du[3] = u[1]*u[2] - (8/3)*u[3]
end

u0 = [1.0;1.0;1.0]
tspan = (0.0,100.0)
prob = ODEProblem(lorenz,u0,tspan)
sol = solve(prob,reltol=1e-8,abstol=1e-8,saveat=collect(0:0.01:100))
```

Loading the packages took about 25 s in the beginning, and the code ran for 7 s on a windows 10 quad core laptop in Jupyter notebook. I understand that Julia need to precompile packages first, and is that why the loading time was so long?  I found 25 s unbearable. Also, when I ran the solver again using different initial values it took much less time (~1s) to run, and why is that? Is this the typical speed?

Comment: `DifferentialEquations` is pre-compiled, so 25 s is definitely not right for it. It's probably `Plots` but even then 25 s sounds too long to me (but I'm on Ubuntu so not sure what plotting is like on Windows 10). Regarding the shorter run the second time round, that is because there is no compilation and is expected.

Comment: Could it be that the 25 s are spent on loading libraries (which still should not take that long, but then you are using Windows)? If you change the differential equations and not just the initial conditions, how long does the second run of the solver take?

Comment: Yes, Plots takes a long time to load

Comment: `Plots` takes > 10 secs to load on my work machines and even longer on old ones.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Tl;dr:

1. Julia packages have a precompilation phase. This helps make all further `using` calls quicker, at the cost of the first one storing some compilation data. This is only triggered each package update.
2. `using` has to pull in the package which takes a little bit (dependent on how much can precompile).
3. Precompilation isn't "complete", so the first time you run a function, even from a package, it will have to compile.
4. Julia devs know about this and there's already plans to get rid of (2) and (3) by making precompilation more complete. There's also plans to reduce compilation time, which I don't know details about.
5. All Julia functions specialize on the types that are given, and each function is a separate type, so DiffEq's internal functions are specializing on each ODE function you give.
6. In most cases with long computations, (5) doesn't actually matter since you aren't changing functions that often (if you are, consider changing parameters instead).
7. But (6) does matter when using it interactively. It makes it feel less "smooth".
8. We can get rid of this specialization on the ODE function, but it isn't the default because it causes a 2x-4x performant hit. Maybe it will be the default in the future.
9. Our timings post precompilation on this problem are still better than things like SciPy's wrapped Fortran solvers on problems like this by 20x. So this is all a compilation time problem, and not a runtime problem. Compilation time is essentially constant (larger problems calling the same function have about the same compilation), so this is really just an interactivity problem.
10. We (and Julia in general) can and will do better with interactivity in the future.

### Full Explanation

This really isn't a DifferentialEquations.jl thing, this is just a Julia package thing. 25s would have to be including the precompilation time. The first time you load a Julia package it precompiles. Then that doesn't need to happen again until the next update. That's probably the longest initialization and it is quite long for DifferentialEquations.jl, but again that only happens each time you update the package code. Then, each time there's a small initialization cost for `using`. DiffEq is quite large, so it does take a bit to initialize:

```
@time using DifferentialEquations
5.201393 seconds (4.16 M allocations: 235.883 MiB, 4.09% gc time)
```

Then as noted in the comments you also have:

```
@time using Plots
6.499214 seconds (2.48 M allocations: 140.948 MiB, 0.74% gc time)
```

Then, the first time you run

```
function lorenz(t,u,du)
  du[1] = 10.0*(u[2]-u[1])
  du[2] = u[1]*(28.0-u[3]) - u[2]
  du[3] = u[1]*u[2] - (8/3)*u[3]
end

u0 = [1.0;1.0;1.0]
tspan = (0.0,100.0)
prob = ODEProblem(lorenz,u0,tspan)
@time sol = solve(prob,reltol=1e-8,abstol=1e-8,saveat=collect(0:0.01:100))

6.993946 seconds (7.93 M allocations: 436.847 MiB, 1.47% gc time)
```

But then the second and third time:

```
0.010717 seconds (72.21 k allocations: 6.904 MiB)
0.011703 seconds (72.21 k allocations: 6.904 MiB)
```

So what's going on here? The first time Julia runs a function, it will compile it. So the first time you run `solve`, it will compile all of its internal functions as it runs. All of the proceeding times will be without the compilation. DifferentialEquations.jl also specializes on the function itself, so if we change the function:

```
function lorenz2(t,u,du)
  du[1] = 10.0*(u[2]-u[1])
  du[2] = u[1]*(28.0-u[3]) - u[2]
  du[3] = u[1]*u[2] - (8/3)*u[3]
end

u0 = [1.0;1.0;1.0]
tspan = (0.0,100.0)
prob = ODEProblem(lorenz2,u0,tspan)
```

we will incur some of the compilation time again:

```
@time sol = 
solve(prob,reltol=1e-8,abstol=1e-8,saveat=collect(0:0.01:100))
3.690755 seconds (4.36 M allocations: 239.806 MiB, 1.47% gc time)
```

So that's the what, now the why. There's a few things together here. First of all, Julia packages do not fully precompile. They don't keep the cached compiled versions of actual methods between sessions. This is something that is on the 1.x release list to do, and this would get rid of that first hit, similar to just calling a C/Fortran package since it would just be hitting a lot of ahead of time (AOT) compiled functions. So that'll be nice, but for now just note that there is a startup time.

Now let's talk about changing the functions. Every function in Julia automatically specializes on its arguments ([see this blog post for details](http://www.stochasticlifestyle.com/7-julia-gotchas-handle/)). The key idea here is that every function in Julia is a separate concrete type. So, since the problem type here is parameterized, changing the function triggers compilation. Note it's that relation: you can change parameters of the function (if you had parameters), you can change the initial conditions, etc., but it's only changing the type that triggers recompilation.

Is it worth it? Well, maybe. We want to specialize to have things fast for calculations which are difficult. Compilation time is constant (i.e. you can solve a 6 hour ODE and it'll still be a few seconds), and so the computationally-costly calculations aren't effected here. Monte Carlo simulations where you're running thousands of parameters and initial conditions aren't effected here because if you're just changing values of initial conditions and parameters then it won't recompile. But interactive use where you are changing functions does get a second or so hit in there, which isn't nice. One answer from the Julia devs for this is to spend post Julia 1.0 time speeding up compilation times, which is something that I don't know the details of but I am assured there's some low hanging fruit here.

Can we get rid of it? Yes. [DiffEq Online](http://app.juliadiffeq.org/) doesn't recompile for each function because it's geared towards online use.

```
function lorenz3(t,u,du)
  du[1] = 10.0*(u[2]-u[1])
  du[2] = u[1]*(28.0-u[3]) - u[2]
  du[3] = u[1]*u[2] - (8/3)*u[3]
  nothing
end

u0 = [1.0;1.0;1.0]
tspan = (0.0,100.0)
f = NSODEFunction{true}(lorenz3,tspan[1],u0)
prob = ODEProblem{true}(f,u0,tspan)

@time sol = solve(prob,reltol=1e-8,abstol=1e-8,saveat=collect(0:0.01:100))

1.505591 seconds (860.21 k allocations: 38.605 MiB, 0.95% gc time)
```

And now we can change the function and not incur compilation cost:

```
function lorenz4(t,u,du)
  du[1] = 10.0*(u[2]-u[1])
  du[2] = u[1]*(28.0-u[3]) - u[2]
  du[3] = u[1]*u[2] - (8/3)*u[3]
  nothing
end

u0 = [1.0;1.0;1.0]
tspan = (0.0,100.0)
f = NSODEFunction{true}(lorenz4,tspan[1],u0)
prob = ODEProblem{true}(f,u0,tspan)

@time sol = 
solve(prob,reltol=1e-8,abstol=1e-8,saveat=collect(0:0.01
:100))

0.038276 seconds (242.31 k allocations: 10.797 MiB, 22.50% gc time)
```

And tada, by wrapping the function in `NSODEFunction` (which is internally using [FunctionWrappers.jl](https://github.com/yuyichao/FunctionWrappers.jl)) it no longer specializes per-function and you hit the compilation time once per Julia session (and then once that's cached, once per package update). But notice that this has about a 2x-4x cost [so I am not sure if it will be enabled by default](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/DiffEqBase.jl/issues/52). We could make this happen by default inside of the problem-type constructor (i.e. no extra specialization by default, but the user can opt into more speed at the cost of interactivity) but I am unsure what the better default is here (feel free to comment on the issue with your thoughts). But it will definitely get documented soon after Julia does its keyword argument changes and so "compilation-free" mode will be a standard way to use it, even if not default.

But just to put it into perspective,

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
y0 = [1.0,1.0,1.0]
t = np.linspace(0, 100, 10001)
def f(u,t):
    return [10.0*(u[1]-u[0]),u[0]*(28.0-u[2])-u[1],u[0]*u[1]-(8/3)*u[2]]
%timeit odeint(f,y0,t,atol=1e-8,rtol=1e-8)

1 loop, best of 3: 210 ms per loop
```

we're looking at whether this interactive convenience should be made a default to be 5x faster instead of 20x faster than SciPy's default here (though our default will usually be much more accurate than the default SciPy uses, but that's data for another time which can be found in the benchmarks or just ask). On one hand it makes sense as ease-of-use, but on the other hand if re-enabling the specialization for long calculations and Monte Carlo isn't known (which is where you really want speed), then lots of people there will take a 2x-4x performance hit which could amount to extra days/weeks of computation. Ehh... tough choices.

So in the end there's a mixture of optimizing choices and some precompilation features missing from Julia that effect the interactivity without effecting the true runtime speed. If you're looking to estimate parameters using some big Monte Carlo, or solve a ton of SDEs, or solve a big PDE, we have that down. That was our first goal and we made sure to hit that as good as possible. But playing around in the REPL does have 2-3 second "gliches" which we also cannot ignore (better than playing around in C/Fortran though of course, but still not ideal for a REPL). For this, I've shown you that there's solutions already being developed and tested, and so hopefully this time next year we can have a better answer for that specific case.

### PS

Two other things to note. If you're only using the ODE solvers, you can just do `using OrdinaryDiffEq` to keep downloading/installing/compiling/importing all of DifferentialEquations.jl ([this is described in the manual](http://diffeq.sciml.ai/stable/features/low_dep.html)). Also, using `saveat` like that probably isn't the fastest way to solve this problem: solving it with a lot less points and using the dense output as necessary may be better here.

### Edit

[I opened an issue detailing how we can reduce the "between function" compilation time without losing the speedup that specializing gives](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/OrdinaryDiffEq.jl/issues/229). I think this is something we can make a short-term priority since I agree that we could do better here.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. So basically the total run time of is the sum of compilation time and computation time, and the compilation time should always be a few seconds? If that's the case I wouldn't mind spending time on that. In this particular case it is because the problem is so simple that the compilation time is much longer than the computation time, am I right?

Comment: Yup, that's the case. It's always a few seconds, but you do feel it if you're doing something quick just one time.

Comment: The precompilation on my machine takes about 5 to 10 minutes, and after that about a minute to load the library each time. I timed it and found that the number of allocations is a lot more than what you reported in your answer above.
>@time using DifferentialEquations
>54.007511 seconds (49.86 M allocations: 2.870 GiB, 3.24% gc time)

Is there something wrong with my setup on arch linux?

Comment: Compilation changed in the 3 1/2 years since this was written. And Julia v1.6 is a big change again. By v1.6 the precompilation time will drop almost an order of magnitude again, but you'll notice that everything in v1.3 precaches a ton more, so first time to plot dropped a ton.